# Can I load a pandas dataframe from a Postgres dump file?

Tags: pandas, postgresql, pg-dump

My Postgres database is locked on a server with no external connectivity, but I can run pg_dump and download the file.

The database contains about 30 tables, but I only need three or four for the dataframe.  They are relational, but they share straightforward IDs, so I don't think that will present any issues.

To be specific, the data is trading logs, and I want to use pandas to analyze the Trade Plans and the resulting trades.  At most, there would be tens or hundreds of thousands of Trade Plans and roughly 4 to 20 executions per Trade Plan.  I don't think the size of the data is anything out of the ordinary.

The tables I need are trade_plans, executions, and closed_positions.

As mentioned in one of the comments, I suppose one possibility is to load the dump file into an available Postgres server and connect pandas to it, but that is not trivial given a large community of users.

Is there any way to load the data into pandas from the dump file?

If pandas doesn't offer this capability, I wonder if there is a utility out there that could convert the dump file to a pandas-friendly format.

I am open to suggestions.

Comment: No a dump file is a text file with SQL commands. Install a server import the data and save the dataframe

Comment: Its an interesting question but agree that the simplest solution is the obvious one: import the data into a postgres server that is not "locked down" and proceed from there. Depending on the very specific details of what is in your dump file and what you are looking for out of it ... there may be weird solutions but without knowing more its impossible to say.

Comment: @nbk, The first problem is a dump file is not necessarily a text file. It could be one of the custom formats which need to be converted to a text file.

Comment: Do you want to load all the data, one table or something in between? Also provide an indication of the size of the data. Add information as text update to question.

Comment: What's the format of the dump? SQL or custom?

Comment: SQL using the standard pg_dump command.  But if there is a custom format that could work, I would consider modifying the export process.

Comment: Use `pg_dump -t <table_name> -a ...` where `-a` is data only. That will get you a COPY statement with tab delimited  data. You read that data into Pandas as tab delimited CSV .

Comment: If you access to the database via `pg_dump` can you also access it with `psql`? If so there maybe a simpler solution that is to use `\copy` from here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) to directly create a CSV file in the format you want and as a stand alone file which you could read directly from Pandas.